# Is there something wrong with my coding? I am still new

Tags: vb.net

I try to run this program but an error always appears:

> Conversion from the string "LBLBuku" to type' Double 'is not valid.

```
If LBLBuku.Text >= 5 Or Val(LBLBuku.Text) + Val(TextBox1.Text) > 5 Then
    MsgBox("Peminjaman Melebihi")
Else
    If lbljudul.Text = "" Or TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Silahkan isi Kode Buku")
    Else
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {TextBox2.Text, lbljudul.Text, LBLPengarang.Text, LBLTahun.Text, TextBox2.Text})
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        lbljudul.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        LBLPengarang.Text = ""
        LBLTahun.Text = ""
        Call rumustotalbuku()
    End If
End If
```

Comment: No there is something wrong with your fundamental problem solving. You'd need to post your code for anyone to help.

Answer (score 3):

Notice on your code the line

```
LBLBuku.Text >= 5
```

The property Text is of type String, you would have to convert the text to an integer type first before you can use ">=".

Answer (score 0):

First I declare a variable to hold the integer value in the Text Box. `Integer.TryParse` will return true if it can convert the string in the text box to an integer. It will also fill the variable `intTB1` with the number.

I am assuming that `LBLBuku` is a label so the `.Text` property has been set from code. We can depend on this being a number so all we need to do is the conversion with `CInt()`. We can use the variable we got from the `.TryParse` in the `Or CInt(LBLBuku.Text) + intTB1 > 5` instead of referring to the text box again.

We don't need to check if `TextBox1` is empty because it wouldn't have passed the `.TryParse` if it was.

Last and probably least, you don't need the `Call` keyword in most situations.

You do realize that you have added `TextBox2` twice to the new DataRow.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim intTB1 As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, intTB1) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number in TextBox1.")
        Return
    End If

    If CInt(LBLBuku.Text) >= 5 Or CInt(LBLBuku.Text) + intTB1 > 5 Then
        MsgBox("Peminjaman Melebihi Maksimal")
    Else
        If lbljudul.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Silahkan isi Kode Buku")
        Else
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {TextBox2.Text, lbljudul.Text, LBLPengarang.Text, LBLTahun.Text, TextBox2.Text})
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            bljudul.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            LBLPengarang.Text = ""
            LBLTahun.Text = ""
            rumustotalbuku()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```